# Google maps api Javascript add onclick to infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I tried to add onclick to my infowindow that after i'll click it it will show a larger infowindow.

For now i'm trying only to show an alert but having trouble with it.

This is my infowindow code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
           return function () {
               var Name = locations[i][0];
               infowindow.setContent(Name + '<button onclick="markerCliked(Name)">Click</button>');
               infowindow.open(map, marker);
           }
       })(marker, i));
```

And my onclick function:

```
function markerCliked(Name){
    alert("Pressed on network " + Name);
}
```

I'm getting an error that Name is not defined.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're creating an element that looks like

```
<button onclick="markerCliked(Name)">Click</button>
```

What does "Name" mean in that context? nothing, this function is not in scope with the function tht created the element, so Name means nothing

you could do

```
infowindow.setContent(Name + '<button onclick="markerCliked(\'' + Name + '\')" >Click</button>');
```

Which creates

```
<button onclick="markerCliked('value of name')">Click</button>
```

`value of name` is the actual value of the variable Name when the button was created ... which would do what you want